# Limit of nth root of polynomial series

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

Let $P(n)$ be a polynomial of positive degree. Show that, $$\lim_{n\to \infty}  \sqrt[n]{ |P(n)|} =1  $$

Here is my attempt, but it's clunky and I'm not 100% sure it if works or not, but here goes (apologies in advanced for formatting);

$$\text{For c > 0,} \ \lim_{n\to\infty}c^{1/n} = 1\quad\text{and}\quad\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{1/n} = 1$$

$$P(n) = a_0+a_1n+a_2n^2+\dots+a_kn^k$$
$$|a_0+a_1+a_2+\dots+a_k|\leq|P(n)|\leq |a_0+a_1n+a_2n^2+\dots+a_kn^k|\quad \text{for all}\ n\geq N$$
$$|a_0+a_1+a_2+\dots+a_k|^{1/n}\leq|P(n)|^{1/n}\leq |a_0+a_1+a_2+\dots+a_k|^{1/n}\cdot n^{k/n}  $$
$$ \text{Let}\ C = a_0+a_1+a_2+\dots+a_k $$
$$|C|^{1/n}\leq |P(n)|^{1/n}\leq |C|^{1/n}\cdot n^{k/n}$$
$$1\leq |P(n)|^{1/n}\leq 1\cdot n^{k/n}$$
$$1\leq P(n) \leq 1\cdot 1^k $$

Thus, using squeeze theorem it has been demonstrated that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|P(n)|}$. Questions: the series $|a_0+a_1+a_2+\dots+a_k|$ is assumed to converge to a constant C. Is this a fair assumption, or would the case that $|a_0+a_1+a_2+\dots+a_k|$ diverges also need to be considered? If it does, the inequality $\infty\leq P(n)\leq\infty\cdot n^{k/n}$ is invalid and squeeze theorem cannot be applied. How is it possible to go around this problem?

Comment: $P$ is a fixed polynomial, and $a_0+a_1+\cdots+a_k$ is definitely a constant. But your left inequality seems to fail if coefficients are allowed to be negative, so you need some adjustment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We'll use the squeeze theorem, but first let us find upper and lower bounds for $|P(n)| = |a_0 + a_1 n + \cdots + a_k n^k|$, assuming of course that $a_k \ne 0$. Note that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{|P(n)|}{n^{k}} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_0}{n^{k}} + \frac{a_1}{n^{k-1}} + \cdots + \frac{a_{k-1}}{n} + a_k\right| = |a_k| > 0.
$$
Hence $\frac{|P(n)|}{n^k}$ is bounded from above and from below by positive constants, i.e.
$$
cn^{k} \le |P(n)| \le Cn^{k}.
$$
For instance you can take $c = |a_k|/2$ and $C = 2|a_k|$ and the inequality will hold for all sufficiently large $n$. You can see this as follows:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{|P(n)|}{n^{k}} = |a_k|
$$
means by definition that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a number $N$ such that $n \ge N$ implies
$$
\left|\frac{|P(n)|}{n^{k}} - |a_k|\right| < \epsilon,
$$
or equivalently,
$$
|a_k| - \epsilon < \frac{|P(n)|}{n^{k}} < |a_k| + \epsilon
$$

First pick $\epsilon = |a_k|$. Then there exists by definition a number $N_1$ such that $n \ge N_1$ implies that
$$
\frac{|P(n)|}{n^{k}} < 2|a_k|.
$$

Repeat the same thing with $\epsilon = |a_k|/2$ to find an $N_2$ such that $n \ge N_2$ implies that
$$
|a_k|/2 = |a_k| - |a_k|/2 < \frac{|P(n)|}{n^{k}}.
$$

Now for $n \ge \max\{N_1, N_2\}$, you get both inequalities.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how using the epsilon limit helps in this case? I understand that it is necessary to set bounds for |P(n)|, but I'm not exactly sure how that translates to ϵ-N.

Comment: From “$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{|P(n)|}{n^{k}} = |a_k|$
means by definition that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a number $N$ such that $n \ge N$ implies $\left|\frac{|P(n)|}{n^{k}} - |a_k|\right| < \epsilon,
$or equivalently,$|a_k| - \epsilon < \frac{|P(n)|}{n^{k}} < |a_k| + \epsilon$…”, we can simply take $\varepsilon=\frac{\left|a_k\right|}{2}$ and then $c=\frac{\left|a_k\right|}{2}$ and $C=\frac{3}{2} \left|a_k\right|$.